# object object output of useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Greetings iam in need of help  so I am taking an online course of react and I followed sir Kalob step by step but while assigning keyword using usestate() it is printing [object object] instead of the actual keyword which I set using hook and so I tried to look for different solutions from
useState("searching for")
I changed it to
useState({name :"searching for"})
and while assigning it to keyword i changed it from
keyword={searchText}
to
keyword={searchText.name}
but still, it's giving me the same output I am out of solutions any help would be appreciated.
All necessary screenshots are attached.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qnf7.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsUog.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ouxl.jpg)

APP.JS

```
import Navbar from './components/navbar';
import Home from './components/home';
import React from 'react';
import SearchView from './components/SearchView'
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import AboutView from './components/AboutView';
import {Routes , Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

function App() {
 const[searchResults,setSearchResults] = useState([]);
 const [searchText,setSearchText] = useState('');
 
  return (
    <div>
    <Navbar searchText={searchText} setSearchText={setSearchText}/>
    <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='/about' element={<AboutView />} />
    <Route path='/search' keyword= {searchText}searchResults={searchResults} element ={<SearchView />} />
    </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.Js

```
// import App from "../App"
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const Navbar = ({searchText,setSearchText}) => {
  const updateSearchText = (e) =>{
    setSearchText(e.target.value)
  }
    return(
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">Movie Browser </Link>
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
        <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link className="nav-link" to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link disabled" href="/">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form className="d-flex" role="search">
          <input className="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" value={searchText}
          onChange={updateSearchText}/>
          <button className="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
      </div>
    )
  }
  export default Navbar;
```

SearchView.js

```
import React from "react";
import Hero from "./Hero";

const SearchView =(keyword,searchResults)=>{
    const title =  `You are searching for ${keyword}`
    console.log(searchResults,"are the search results")
    return(
        <div>
            <Hero text ={title} />
        </div>
    )
}
export default SearchView;
```

Comment: Please provide your code as actual text. Images of text cannot be copied or modified, so that makes them very hard to work with.

Comment: You're not even passing props to `SearchView`, how is it even getting anything there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the props that `SearchView` should have through the `element` prop while calling the component.

```
<Route 
  path='/search' 
  element={
    <SearchView keyword={searchText} searchResults={searchResults} />
  } 
/>
```

And your output is `[object Object]` because you're logging the `props` object, not the `keyword` string. Add the destructuring assignment of the props to actually get the props that are being passed.

```
const SearchView = ({ keyword, searchResults }) => {
  const title = `You are searching for ${keyword}`;

  return (
    <div>
      <Hero text ={title} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping sir after applying your method my search page is now empty and there was an error upon search I get to know that props is replaced by keyword "element" and so after applying this code my whole hero section isn't showing and error presist

"Matched leaf route at location "/search" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page."

`<Route path='/search' render ={(element)=><SearchView {...element}keyword = {searchText} searchResults ={searchResults}/>}/>`

Comment: I must have gotten an old example of a `Route` implementation. The docs are hard to find for some reason. Try the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping it works perfectly well for me now I still had to tweak the "component" keyword to 'element' to make it work otherwise the syntax is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Working late night made me miss that. Though it's alway called a component in React, but not with React Router, it seems.

Comment: Either way you helped me a lot thank you for your help